# -static flag leads to “error: C compiler cannot create executables”

Tags: build

The compiler here is `gcc` (v. 6.2.0).

If I add `-static` to either `LDFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS`, the `./configure` step of an Emacs build fails, with the error

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

How can I troubleshoot this error further?  (I am already running `./configure` with the `--verbose` flag, but it still tells me very little about the reason for the error.)

FWIW, I want to build a static instance of Emacs, because the site where I work does not support Emacs at all ("Emacs?  What's that?  Why don't you use vi?  Or nano?"), and the version of it they offer is prehistoric.

Comment: Judging from this: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-09/msg00094.html not even the people on the mailing list ever did this. Regarding the error: it's very generic and may mean a bunch of things, but you really need to also show the line before that, that's the line that is causing it.